# DateTime filter return a wrong result

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the followinf DataFrame "df":

```
DateTime
2019-03-07 23:00:00
2019-03-07 23:10:00
2019-03-08 23:10:00
2019-03-09 23:10:00
2019-03-10 23:10:00
2019-03-11 23:10:00
2019-03-12 23:10:00

df.dtypes:
DateTime              datetime64[ns]
```

I need to return rows before "2019-03-11".
This is my current code:

```
value_to_check = pd.Timestamp(2019, 3, 11)
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateTime"])

df[df["DateTime"]<value_to_check]
# OR
df.query('DateTime < "2019-03-11 00:00:00"').tail()
```

For some reason it returns a wrong result (missing "2019-03-10 23:10:00"):

```
2019-03-07 23:00:00
2019-03-07 23:10:00
2019-03-08 23:10:00
2019-03-09 23:10:00
```

But surprisingly it works well if I change the day limit to any number lower than 10, e.g "2019-03-08 00:00:00".

Comment: That is strange behaviour? Can you add the output of `python -m pip show pandas` and can you substitute `value_to_check = pd.Timestamp(2019, 3, 11)` to `value_to_check = datetime(2019, 3, 11) #from datetime import datetime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run this code and output is correct:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DateTime': ["2019-03-07 23:00:00", 
                 "2019-03-07 23:10:00",
                 "2019-03-08 23:10:00",
                 "2019-03-09 23:10:00",
                 "2019-03-10 23:10:00",
                 "2019-03-11 23:10:00",
                 "2019-03-12 23:10:00"
                ]
})
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateTime"])
print(df["DateTime"])

value_to_check = pd.Timestamp(2019, 3, 11)
df[df["DateTime"]<value_to_check]
```

Output:

```
0   2019-03-07 23:00:00
1   2019-03-07 23:10:00
2   2019-03-08 23:10:00
3   2019-03-09 23:10:00
4   2019-03-10 23:10:00
5   2019-03-11 23:10:00
6   2019-03-12 23:10:00
Name: DateTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]

    DateTime
0   2019-03-07 23:00:00
1   2019-03-07 23:10:00
2   2019-03-08 23:10:00
3   2019-03-09 23:10:00
4   2019-03-10 23:10:00
```

Comment: For some reason it does not work on my data. Any idea what should I double-check to detect the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Compare `DateTime` column to a string works:

```
>>> df[df['DateTime'] < '2019-03-11']
             DateTime
0 2019-03-07 23:00:00
1 2019-03-07 23:10:00
2 2019-03-08 23:10:00
3 2019-03-09 23:10:00
4 2019-03-10 23:10:00
```

This works too:

```
df[df['DateTime'] < pd.Timestamp(2019, 3, 11)]

df.query('DateTime < "2019-03-11 00:00:00"')
```

What is your version of Python and Pandas?

Comment: Is this not the same code that OP says is not working?

Comment: Yes, this is why I want to know the versions are used

Comment: It's Python 3.6 and pandas 0.25.3. No, your code gives the same wrong result as my code.

Comment: That is what I thought. Can you update Pandas? I guess not?

Comment: Which version do you suggest?

Comment: Pandas will not be updated with Python 3.6... The latest version of Pandas for Python 3.6 is 0.25.3....

Comment: Tested with Python 3.6.9 and Pandas 0.25.3. All works well. I really don't understand your problem :-(